# import a mongodb into cosmo db

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have a mongo db collection that has a 2d sphere index on a Location field that is an object with lat and lng elements. Can I import this into cosmo db and use it as is? The index is used for geoNear queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Try and report how it goes.